# RNCamera crashes in iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, camera, react-native-camera

I'm developing a video recording app in React Native and I'm using 'react-native-camera' package.
Of course, I used RNCamera and the thing is it's fine in android but crashes in iOS.
When I open the screen where RNCamera is used, the app just crashes and turn off.
I can't get information why this issue occurs.
If anyone has experience with this problem, I beg your help.
Thank you.

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-camera": "3.15.0"

<RNCamera
    ref={ref => {
        this.camera = ref;
    }}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
/>
```

Comment: On iOS simulator camera is not supported. Is this happening on simulator or real device?

Comment: It's real device.

Comment: So try to run your app with Xcode, and read the error on Xcode console. Search it or update your question with thrown error for more help.

Comment: Have you added camera permission in info.plist ?

Comment: Yes, I added permission.

Comment: whether this issue is fixed ..Please post the answer.. it will help others

Answer (score 1):

key to me was to follow that part of the instructions:
*You may also need to reset your simulator data after adding those permissions Device -> Erase All Content and Settings...* It then stopped crashing the simulator on iOS